# C# cast analogous to C++ reinterpret_cast

Tags: c#, casting

Is there an equivalent of the C++ reinterpret_cast in C#?

I want to know if this is possible:

```
class ClassX
{
    public void X() { }
}

class ClassY
{
    public void Y() { }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassX x = new ClassX();
        ClassY y = (ClassY)x; // is it possible to cast like this?
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do that if class Y is derived from classX

Comment: Yes. I want to know if a cast can be done across unrelated types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't. In C++ the behaviour on your doing that is *undefined* since the types are not related.

C# holds your hand more tightly and forbids this.

Comment: Just found this. Casting is possible if you cast to an interface. Weird!

`code`
    interface I
    {
        void f();
    }

    class A
    {
    }

    class B
    {
        public void f(A a)
        {
            var b = (I)a;   // that's weird but it compiles
            b.f();
        }
    }
`code`

Comment: @user3009098: it compiles, because there's not enough information at compile-time for the compiler to know for sure the code is broken (the `A` could be a subclass of `A` that implements `I`). But it will still fail at runtime, because the `a` object does not in fact implement `I`. This is not anything like a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible unless you explicitly define how. Otherwise the compiler will block you from doing that as it would cause an unsafe handling of references.

For C# to know a way how to interpret that you can do the following:

Either `ClassX` must inherit from `ClassY` like this:

```
public ClassX : ClassY { }
```

Or implement an operator to do so explicitly

```
public ClassX
{
    public static explicit operator ClassY(ClassX x)
    {
        return new ClassX() // and implement how to convert it here.
    }
}
```

Both do not exactly do what you would expect from C++ and create additional overhead and memory usage, however both are guaranteed to work for a casting operation.